# Need some advice with regexp (php)

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

> ('Afghanistan','3',''**),('** Albania','1','90 days'**),('**
>   Algeria','3',''**),('** Andorra','3',''**),('** Angola','3','')... etc

I need to select spaces after: **),('**

Can someone help me plz?

Comment: Just select the spaces?  And then what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why regexp? Just use `str_replace("),(' ","),('", $myString);`

**edit**: `),('` was per your request. But I advise you to only look for `('`, because the very first entry might also contain a space, but isn't caught with the string you requested.

So use `str_replace("(' ","('", $myString);`

Comment: Someone is awake here!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this :

```
$pattern = "~(?<=\Q),('\E) ~";
```

all between `\Q` and `\E` are seen as literals.

`(?<=.....)` means *preceded by*

Comment: `\Q` and `\E`, I love learning new things! No longer do I need to write things like `\),\(`, +1

Comment: @Sam: Me too, but be careful, this doesn't work with delimiters!

Comment: @Sam Sometimes people put in much effort to make a regex look as fancy as possible - but still missing the `'` so this regex does not deserve any upvote.

Comment: @dognose -- I wouldn't say that this necessarily means they don't deserve an upvote..good catch, though. None of the other ones really deserve upvotes either without an explanation..at least here OP can read it, understand it, and figure out how to add the `'`. That will actually teach them something, rather than copy/pasting.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte And now escape the `'` you just added :) !

Comment: @Sam: ...and with the string quotes!

Comment: Haha, speak of the devil, eh?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have described your input perfectly, this should do the trick.

```
(?<='\),\(') *
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with following regex:

```
/\),\('( )/
```